# How do i put a motherboard into the case?

Tags: motherboard, case

I never built my own desktop but i have played with parts (harddrive, ram, optical drive, wifi chip). I heard that if i don't put the motherboard into the case correctly it will fry. Than i heard something about risers and putting the board on that.

How do i properly put a motherboard to a case? Is it obvious when i am doing it wrong?

I'm looking at this picture and i don't see any 'risers' or how to install the motherboard w/o frying it.

[image]

Comment: Most motherboards come with a manual or a link to one, read it carefully.

Comment: @Moab: It sucked :(. It explained layout but nothing about screws, standoffs and other various things

Comment: Nice guide here...http://computershopper.com/feature/75-pc-building-tips-motherboard-case-installation

Answer (score 1):

Risers are typically included with cases or MOBO's. I like to take the case apart and screw in the risers after matching up the mobo with the holes in the case. Make sure your mobo is the right form factor for the case. It is very easy and you will know how to do it when you see it.

Connecting the USB and power button is the most irritating part. Make sure you use all of the risers or one section of the board's stability will be compromised and broken/chipped mobos do happen because people do not use all of their risers because they are in a hurry.

Comment: At least here in the States, I generally see them called 'standoffs' rather than 'risers'.

Comment: And in Sweden, I often see "spacers".

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good chance that there are some screws on the other side of the case (the hidden side in the picture).  Take that side panel off, undo a few screws and the motherboard tray should come right out.

You then place the motherboard on the tray with the risers and such you'd typically get with the case, put the tray back in and go on to the next several steps of assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the screw holes on the motherboard match up with the risers on the case, no other part of the MB should come into contact with any metal of the case. If there is any riser without a corresponding screw hole on the MB remove it.